# How to define a lambda function inside a struct in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

is there any possibility to have a lambda expression inside a struct in c++ . logic goes as follows.

```
struct alpha {
  <lambda function> {
   /* to do */
}

};

int main()
{
int a =   //call the function inside the struct and compute.

}
```

Comment: why you need a lambda function and not a normal member function? Please, elaborate your use case, since this seems to be an XY problem

Comment: Of course it's possible! It's called a "class method". It effectively captures `this`, plus whatever parameters you pass into it. See your C++ book for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use `std::function`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Foo
{
    const std::function<void()> hello = [] () { std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl; };
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo {};
    foo.hello();
}
```

See [live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9a1a99fa2219aa5).

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you're asking exactly.
But a lambda, a.k.a. [a functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses), in C++ is mainly syntactic sugar for `operator()`.
If you want to have a "callable" struct, you can just define `operator()` like this:

```
struct alpha {
    int operator() () {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main()
{
    alpha x;
    int a = x();
    std::cout << a << std::endl; // prints "42"

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use std :: function to declare a pointer to a function, and when initializing the structure, substitute a function with the lambda pointer, for example
    `struct alpha{
     std::function<int(int)>
};
...
alpha a{[](int a){return a;}};`